Получение видео по udp от ROC-RK35
У меня есть устройство с rockchip rk3588. Компьютер и этот вычислитель находятся в одной wifi сети и видят друг друга. Видеопоток на экране рокчипа получается с аналоговых камер и отображается на экране, вот его конфигурация
{"identifier": "right","source": "rtspsrc location=rtsp://192.168.1.:5/channel=1&stream=0.sdp user-id=****** user-pw=****** tcp-timeout=5000000","parser": "rtph265depay ! h265parse ","decoder": "mppvideodec width=1280 height=720","postprocessor": "videoflip video-direction=5","remote_enabled": true,"remote_host": "192.168.2.2","remote_port": 49023,"sink": "appsink name=sink sync=false","frame": {"width": 1280,"height": 720,"channels": 3}},

здесь прописано что он отсылает udp датаграммы на соответствующий порт моего компьютера. Компьютер на основе анализа wireshark успешно получает эти udp пакеты.
Приложение на компьютере прослушивает этот порт с помощью следующий конфигурации
rc::stream::StreamConfig config {.identifier = "",.source = "udpsrc port=49023 caps="application/x-rtp, payload=98"",.parser = "rtph265depay ! h265parse",.decoder = "avdec_h265",.postprocessor = "",.sink = "appsink name=sink sync=false",.frame_shape = {.width = 1280,.height = 720,.channels = 3}};  

значение payload и caps корректны - взяты из отправителя.
Собранный пайплайн выглядит у меня следующим образом:
udpsrc port=49023 caps="application/x-rtp, payload=98" ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! avdec_h265 ! appsink name=sink sync=false

 case State::kConnecting: {
        if (!active_.load(std::memory_order::relaxed)) {
          local_active = false;
          continue;
        }
        //std::string pipeline_str = source_;

        //фомируем строку  pipeline
        // if(remote_enabled_) {
        //   pipeline_str = EnableStreamingPipeline();
        //
        // } else {
        //   pipeline_str = DisableStreamingPipeline();
        // }
          std::string pipeline_str = source_;

          if (!parser_.empty())
              pipeline_str = fmt::format("{} ! {}", pipeline_str, parser_);

          if (!decoder_.empty())
              pipeline_str = fmt::format("{} ! {}", pipeline_str, decoder_);

          if (!postprocessor_.empty())
              pipeline_str = fmt::format("{} ! {}", pipeline_str, postprocessor_);

          pipeline_str = fmt::format("{} ! {}", pipeline_str, sink_);

          logger_->info(pipeline_str);

           GError* error;
           pipeline = gst_parse_launch(pipeline_str.c_str(), &error);
             if (error) {
                 logger_->error("Ошибка создания pipeline: {} " ,error->message );
                 g_error_free(error);
             }
         //pipeline = gst_parse_launch(pipeline_str.c_str(), nullptr);







        ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

        if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
          logger_->error("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state ({}).", pipeline_str);
          gst_object_unref(pipeline);
          active_.store(false, std::memory_order::relaxed);
        }

        appsink = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "sink");
        g_object_set(appsink, "emit-signals", TRUE, nullptr);

        g_signal_connect(appsink,
                         "new-sample",
                         G_CALLBACK(static_cast<NewSampleCallback>([](GstElement* sink, Stream* stream) {
                           return stream->NewSample(sink);
                         })),
                         this);

        bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);

        logger_->info("Constructed pipeline.");
        state = State::kStreaming;

        break;
      }
      case State::kStreaming: {
        if (!active_.load(std::memory_order::relaxed)) {
          state = State::kFinishing;
          continue;
        }

        msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, TimeCountIn<nanoseconds>(kBusTimeout),
                                         static_cast<GstMessageType>(GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS | GST_MESSAGE_PROGRESS));

        if (msg == nullptr) {
            logger_->info("Received nullptr message");
        } else {
            logger_->info("Received message type: {}", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME(msg));
        }
        if (msg != nullptr) {
          switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
            case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {
              GError* err;
              gchar* debug_info;
              gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
              logger_->error("Error received from element {}: {}", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
              g_clear_error(&err);
              g_free(debug_info);
              Reset(bus, pipeline);
              state = State::kConnecting;
              break;
            }
            case GST_MESSAGE_EOS: {
              logger_->info("Connection list (EOS).");
              Reset(bus, pipeline);
              state = State::kConnecting;
              break;
            }
            case GST_MESSAGE_PROGRESS: {
              GstProgressType type;
              gchar* progress_code;
              gchar* progress_text;
              gst_message_parse_progress(msg, &type, &progress_code, &progress_text);
              if (type == GST_PROGRESS_TYPE_COMPLETE && std::string(progress_code) == "request")
                logger_->info("Started streaming");
              break;
            }
            default:
              break;
          }
          gst_message_unref(msg);
        }

        break;
      }

Во время работы msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered возвращает всегда nullptr по этой причине видео в дальнейшем не отображается в моем окошке qt.
пробовал запустить через командную строку и вот вывод$ gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc port=49023 caps="application/x-rtp, payload=98" ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! avdec_h265 ! appsink name=sink sync=false

Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...Pipeline is PREROLLED ...Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...New clock: GstSystemClock/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0.GstPad:src: caps = application/x-rtp, payload=(int)98, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H265/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRtpH265Depay:rtph265depay0.GstPad:sink: caps = application/x-rtp, payload=(int)98, media=(string)video, clock-rate=(int)90000, encoding-name=(string)H265

